# Meaning of declarations in /etc/init.d/functions on EL 5

Tags: linux, bash, function, init.d

I'm something of an amateur when it comes to Bash shell scripting and am baffled by this first line in the killproc() function in /etc/init.d/functions on a CentOS 5.10 system:

```
local RC killlevel= base pid pid_file= delay try
```

What is the meaning of that line? I believe it is the declaration of local variables perhaps, but what is the meaning of the = after a couple of the items? I have included the complete killproc() function below for reference:

```
# A function to stop a program.
killproc() {
    local RC killlevel= base pid pid_file= delay try

    RC=0; delay=3; try=0
    # Test syntax.
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $"Usage: killproc [-p pidfile] [ -d delay] {program} [-signal]"
        return 1
    fi
    if [ "$1" = "-p" ]; then
        pid_file=$2
        shift 2
    fi
    if [ "$1" = "-d" ]; then
        delay=$(echo $2 | awk -v RS=' ' -v IGNORECASE=1 '{if($1!~/^[0-9.]+[smhd]?$/) exit 1;d=$1~/s$|^[0-9.]*$/?1:$1~/m$/?60:$1~/h$/?60*60:$1~/d$/?24*60*60:-1;if(d==-1) exit 1;delay+=d*$1} END {printf("%d",delay+0.5)}')
        if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then
            echo $"Usage: killproc [-p pidfile] [ -d delay] {program} [-signal]"
            return 1
        fi
        shift 2
    fi


    # check for second arg to be kill level
    [ -n "${2:-}" ] && killlevel=$2

        # Save basename.
        base=${1##*/}

        # Find pid.
    __pids_var_run "$1" "$pid_file"
    if [ -z "$pid_file" -a -z "$pid" ]; then
        pid="$(__pids_pidof "$1")"
    fi

        # Kill it.
        if [ -n "$pid" ] ; then
                [ "$BOOTUP" = "verbose" -a -z "${LSB:-}" ] && echo -n "$base "
        if [ -z "$killlevel" ] ; then
               if checkpid $pid 2>&1; then
               # TERM first, then KILL if not dead
               kill -TERM $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
               usleep 100000
               if checkpid $pid ; then
                try=0
                while [ $try -lt $delay ] ; do
                    checkpid $pid || break
                    sleep 1
                    let try+=1
                done
                if checkpid $pid ; then
                    kill -KILL $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
                    usleep 100000
                fi
               fi
                fi
            checkpid $pid
            RC=$?
            [ "$RC" -eq 0 ] && failure $"$base shutdown" || success $"$base shutdown"
            RC=$((! $RC))
        # use specified level only
        else
                if checkpid $pid; then
                        kill $killlevel $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
                RC=$?
                [ "$RC" -eq 0 ] && success $"$base $killlevel" || failure $"$base $killlevel"
            elif [ -n "${LSB:-}" ]; then
                RC=7 # Program is not running
            fi
        fi
    else
        if [ -n "${LSB:-}" -a -n "$killlevel" ]; then
            RC=7 # Program is not running
        else
            failure $"$base shutdown"
            RC=0
        fi
    fi

        # Remove pid file if any.
    if [ -z "$killlevel" ]; then
            rm -f "${pid_file:-/var/run/$base.pid}"
    fi
    return $RC
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just declaring a lot of function scope variables, where `killlevel` and `pid_file` are assigned the empty string and the others are not assigned anything.

There is a slight difference. `local` variables are also visible in functions called from the function. So if you happen to call `killproc()` recursively, the uninitialized ones are remembered from the caller.

On Debian the `lib/lsb/init-functions` file looks like this:

```
killproc() {
    local pidfile sig status base name_param is_term_sig OPTIND
    pidfile=                                                   
    name_param=                                                
    is_term_sig=
```

Comment: And [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) is a reference from the bash manual.